# XCode does not compile/run/clean after quick multiple runs

Tags: xcode

I've been facing this problem with XCode 4.2 onwards. These days its turning out to be really annoying. I'm running XCode 4.6 and this issue still persists.
If I quickly save (Command + S) and run (Command + R) the project multiple times, making small changes to the project, it finally doesnt compile atall. Have to Force Quit XCode and reopen it. Everything else works but for compiling.

Is anyone else having the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling this issue has been fixed in XCode5. Been using it for a few days and I havent encountered this problem till date.